# How do I properly use the jQuery off() method to remove the mouseenter and mouseleave events off an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to be having some trouble removing some events from an element using the jQuery off() method. I want to remove the mouseenter and mouseleave events when I match a certain criteria.

Heres what I got.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GE7Wg/

On the above fiddle, Article 2 should NOT have a mouseenter/mouseleave event associated with it.

Thanks!

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>   
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenMediaID" value="450">

    <article class="Article">
        Article 1                
        <input type="hidden" class="LatestMediaID" value="200" />
    </article>

    <article class="Article">
        Article 2
        <input type="hidden" class="LatestMediaID" value="450" />
    </article>

    <article class="Article">
        Article 3
        <input type="hidden" class="LatestMediaID" value="700" />
    </article> 
</body>
</html>
```

### jQuery

```
//Page loaded - jQuery Ready
$(document).ready(function () {   
    //User hovering over article. Change BG.
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.Article', function () {
        $(this).css('background', '#F0F8FF');
    }).on('mouseleave', '.Article', function () {
        $(this).css('background', '#FFFFFF');
    });

    //Set active BG color if condition is met.
    $('.LatestMediaID').each(function () {
        var LatestMediaID = $(this).val();     

        //Disable mouseenter and mouseleave events on the matched Article.
        if (LatestMediaID == $('#HiddenMediaID').val()) {
            //Disable events.
            $(document).off('mouseenter', $(this).parent());
            $(document).off('mouseleave', $(this).parent());

            //Change BG color to light blue.    
            $(this).parent().css('background', '#F0F8FF');
        }
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
.Article {
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;    
}
```

​

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ is what you looking for.

Comment: `on` and `off` don't work quite the way you expect. One you've applied a delegated listener with `on`, you cannot *partially* undo the listener. `off` can only completely undo the effects of the `on` call; you cannot prevent the listener from applying to one of the elements without undoing it for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do some DOM manipulations and throw some conditions

```
//Page loaded - jQuery Ready
$(document).ready(function () {

    //User hovering over article. Change BG.
    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.Article', function () {
        if( !( $(this).hasClass('donotSelect') ) )
            $(this).css('background', '#F0F8FF');
        else
             $(document).off('mouseleave', $(this));
    }).on('mouseleave', '.Article', function () {
        if( !( $(this).hasClass('donotSelect') ) )
            $(this).css('background', '#FFFFFF');
        else
             $(document).off('mouseenter', $(this));
    });

    //Set active BG color if condition is met.
    $('.LatestMediaID').each(function () {
        var LatestMediaID = $(this).val();     

        //Disable mouseenter and mouseleave events on the matched Article.
        if (LatestMediaID == $('#HiddenMediaID').val()) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("donotSelect");
            //Change BG color to light blue.    
            $(this).parent().css('background', '#F0F8FF');
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GE7Wg/5/

Comment: I like that this solves the problem, but the OP specifically stated that he/she would like to remove the events. Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't the events still bound to the element in this answer?

Comment: Umm, I don't think so because class 'donotSelect' wouldn't be assigned anything on mouseenter or mouseleave. That is why there is no effect on Article 2!

Comment: Right, but the mouseenter and mouseleave events are still bound to the element. They're just not firing because of 'donotselect'

Comment: @hackNightly I have improvised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what his causing the problem, but you could avoid adding the events in the first place by checking the value up front.

Maybe use something like:

```
$(function() {
    var hidID = $("#HiddenMediaID").val();
    $(".Article").each(function(){
        var article = $(this);
        if(article.find(".LatestMediaID").val() !== hidID)
        {
            article.on("mouseenter", function(){ article.css("background", "#F0F8FF") });
            article.on("mouseleave", function(){ article.css("background", "#FFFFFF") });
        }
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it the way you want by adding another event on the selected article level http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ from there, but thas is really ugly. Much cleaner to handle this via CSS http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/GE7Wg/4/

```
.selected, .hover { background-color:#F0F8FF;}​
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.Article', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("hover", e.type == "mouseenter");
});
```